# how do I combine code for two different arrow key's with two different vars?

Tags: javascript, css, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have some code where the arrow key down is triggerd. But I want the same code but with another var and with the arrow key left in state of the arrow key down. I have in this code 2 div's, and it's a bar that is draw in css. When you hold the arrow key down you see the value is changing. I want the same but with two other div's en the arrow key left. How do you add that code, and both works.

```
var changeIdValue = function () {
 var current = document.getElementById('balklongwaarde').clientHeight - 15 + 'px';
'use strict'
document.getElementById('balklongwaarde').style.height = current;
var current = document.getElementById('balklevensverwachting').clientHeight - 7.5 + 'px';
'use strict'
document.getElementById('balklevensverwachting').style.height = current;
};

var intervalID;

 //through arrow down values are changing//
window.onkeydown = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    if(typeof intervalID == 'undefined') {
        intervalID = window.setInterval(changeIdValue, 10);       
    }
};



//through arrow down values are changing//
 window.onkeyup = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID= undefined;

 }
};
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhTU9/
in jsfiddle I have add the code for the arrow key left, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addEventListener` to bind multiple callbacks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MhTU9/2/).

Code DRY version.

```
function bind(callback, keyCode) {
    var interval;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === keyCode) {
            if(typeof interval === 'undefined') {
                interval = setInterval(callback, 10);
            }
        }
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === keyCode) {
            interval = clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, false)
}

bind(changeIdValue, 37);
bind(changeWaarde, 40);
```